# Why can't I return a LuaObject in a function when using LuaPlus?

Tags: c++, pointers, lua, luaplus

I am following an example in Game Coding Complete 4th Edition, which uses LuaPlus.

In the example, and in any code i have tried myself, I am unable to register a function to lua if it has a return value of LuaObject.

```
LuaObject myClass::CreateFromScript(void)
{
Player* pCppInstance = new Player();

LuaObject luaInstance;
luaInstance.AssignNewTable(pLuaState);

luaInstance.SetLightUserData("__object", pCppInstance);

LuaObject metaTable = pLuaState->GetGlobals().GetByName("Players");
luaInstance.SetMetaTable(metaTable);

return luaInstance;
}
```

and

```
globals.RegisterDirect("createPlayer", &myClass::CreateFromScript);
```

and in .h

```
static LuaObject                CreateFromScript(void);
```

The error always happens when I set the return value to LuaObject. Which is why I was unable to do this earlier when I tried returning a LuaObject with a different function in my code.

```
error: LuaPlusCD.h (line 158)
"no matching function for call to 'Push(lua_State*&, LuaPlus::LuaObject&)'
```

Comment: This is all I could find on the matter, and I can't tell if it's the same problem.

https://github.com/jjensen/luaplus51-all/issues/4

Comment: Just to note, I am using Lua 5.1 with the latest version of LuaPlus.  I am also using Code::Blocks, GNU GCC Compiler, Mingw